# How to encode php array in json and parse into jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am fetching record with drop down using ajax call but the problem is that it is fetching only one record while there are three records in the database

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include 'config/dbconfig.php';

$genid      = $_POST['id'];
$operatorId = $_POST['operatorId'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM generatorrun WHERE generatorId='$genid' AND operatorId='$operatorId'");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $turnOn           = $result['startTime'];
    $turnOff          = $result['endTime'];
    $datetime1        = new DateTime($turnOn);
    $datetime2        = new DateTime($turnOff);
    $interval         = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $datedifference   = $interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
    $startReading     = $result['startReading'];
    $endReading       = $result['endReading'];
    $dailyConsumption = $endReading - $startReading;

    $postData = array(
        "turnOn"           => $turnOn,
        "turnOff"          => $turnOff,
        "runningTime"      => $datedifference,
        "startReading"     => $startReading,
        "endReading"       => $endReading,
        "dailyConsumption" => $dailyConsumption,
    );
}

echo json_encode($postData);
?>
```

I have to fetch the values from MySQL and stored in an associative array and then encoding it with `json_encode()` function.

and this is the code for fetching the record in jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bg-yellow").hide();
    $(".bg-red").hide();
    $("#getGen").change(function () {

        var id = $('#getGen').val();
        var operatorId = $(".opid").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'getGenerator.php',
            data: {id: id, operatorId: operatorId},
            success: function (response) {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                $(".turnOn").html(data.turnOn);
                $(".turnOff").html(data.turnOff);
                $(".running").html(data.runningTime);
                $(".startReading").html(data.startReading);
                $(".endReading").html(data.endReading);
                $(".dailyConsumption").html(data.dailyConsumption);
                $(".bg-yellow").show();
                $(".bg-red").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

the problem is that it is fetching only one record and I have used while loop to iterate through all records which are in MySQL table but it is only fetching only one record

Comment: `$postData[] = array(`. You know what `[]` means, right?

Comment: yes i have also tried with this way but the result is same

Comment: What does it means - the same? What do you see in a console? If you have array of items - you need to iterate over them.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop you are assigning the variable. So every loop it overides the values. You must use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
$postData = array();
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$turnOn=$result['startTime'];
$turnOff=$result['endTime'];
$datetime1 = new DateTime($turnOn);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($turnOff);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$datedifference=$interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
$startReading=$result['startReading'];
$endReading=$result['endReading'];
$dailyConsumption=$endReading-$startReading;
  array_push($postData,array(
    "turnOn" => $turnOn,
    "turnOff" => $turnOff,
    "runningTime"=>$datedifference,
    "startReading"=>$startReading,
    "endReading"=>$endReading,
    "dailyConsumption"=>$dailyConsumption
    ));
  }
```

Comment: how to parse this kind of array in json

Comment: how to parse it into jquery

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define an array.

```
<?php
include 'config/dbconfig.php';

$postData = array();
$genid=$_POST['id'];
$operatorId=$_POST['operatorId'];

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM generatorrun WHERE generatorId='$genid' AND operatorId='$operatorId'");

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $turnOn=$result['startTime'];
    $turnOff=$result['endTime'];
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($turnOn);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($turnOff);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    $datedifference=$interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
    $startReading=$result['startReading'];
    $endReading=$result['endReading'];
    $dailyConsumption=$endReading-$startReading;

    $postData[] = array(
        "turnOn" => $turnOn,
        "turnOff" => $turnOff,
        "runningTime"=>$datedifference,
        "startReading"=>$startReading,
        "endReading"=>$endReading,
        "dailyConsumption"=>$dailyConsumption
    );
}

echo json_encode($postData);
?>
```

Comment: json parsing is empty from this method

Comment: i am getting empty json

Comment: use document.write(response); for test the response

Comment: Can i use alert?

Comment: you also need to use for loop inside the query

Comment: can you please make a solution

Comment: can you give me your json response ?

Comment: you need like this for loop and check the result first.   for(var i=0;i<count(response);i++){
    
}

Comment: the problem is inside the jquery parsing i think

Comment: yes you just need the check how to handle json response by using loop

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
include 'config/dbconfig.php';
$genid      = $_POST['id'];
$operatorId = $_POST['operatorId'];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM generatorrun WHERE generatorId='$genid' AND operatorId='$operatorId'");
$postData = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

$turnOn           = $result['startTime'];
$turnOff          = $result['endTime'];
$datetime1        = new DateTime($turnOn);
$datetime2        = new DateTime($turnOff);
$interval         = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$datedifference   = $interval->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
$startReading     = $result['startReading'];
$endReading       = $result['endReading'];
$dailyConsumption = $endReading - $startReading;

$postData[] = array( // this is you missed here
        "turnOn"           => $turnOn,
        "turnOff"          => $turnOff,
        "runningTime"      => $datedifference,
        "startReading"     => $startReading,
        "endReading"       => $endReading,
        "dailyConsumption" => $dailyConsumption,
);
}
```

It will give you multiple results sets.